# PostgreSQL SQL Query to return all graph nodes (the connected components), provided a node to query upon

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph, subgraph

In my Postgresql DB I have one or more directed acyclic graphs, represented by the following tables:

Tables:

```
nodes_table
    id

edges_table
    id
    parent_id -- a nodes_table id
    child_id -- a nodes_table id
```

Assuming I have the following data, here is an example with 3 separate graphs stored in the database. Note, there is no connection between any of these three graphs with each other:

```
nodes_table
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13

edges_table
1, 1, 2
2, 1, 5
3, 2, 3
4, 3, 4
5, 5, 10
6, 9, 5
7, 9, 11
8, 3, 10
9, 6, 7
10, 8, 12
11, 8, 13

Output (3 separate graph structures, with the roots at the top):
 
  1   9         6       8
 / \ / \        |      / \
2   5   11      7     12 13
|   |
|   |
3   |
| \ |
4   10
```

Is there a way that I can get all nodes connected in *any way* (including through other nodes, up and down a given graph) provided a query node?

If I query *any* node in the leftmost graph, I want my query to return *all* nodes in that graph (excluding any nodes from other graphs in the database)

Maybe another way to think of this is that for this query I want to treat the graph as if it were an undirected graph, and return all nodes that have *any* path to the queried node.

I found [this answer, which finds all of the connected subgraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36687252/9712989) in a similar table structure, but it seems overboard for what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to return just one subgraph - specifically the one which includes the node I want to query upon. I suppose I could filter the output for the node I'm interested in, but that seems inefficient - searching the entire set of graphs and then just returning one. There has got to be a better way, but I'm still pretty new to SQL.

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49753508/select-subgraph-of-all-connected-nodes-based-on-node-id) regarding graphs in R, and [an approach using NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350355/9712989), but I really want to do this in the database and not in external code.

---

Edit: I also found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37382147/9712989), but it doesn't seem to work as expected. If I select node 1 as the starting point, all's good. But other nodes within the same graph don't provide the expected output of all the nodes in that graph. [Here's an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d2f831/5) based on that answer. Thoughts? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all related nodes.

For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select 5 as id -- starting node
 union
  select case when e.child_id = n.id then e.parent_id else e.child_id end
  from n
  join edges_table e on e.parent_id = n.id or e.child_id = n.id
)
select * from n
```

Result:

```
id 
-- 
5  
1  
10 
9  
2  
3  
11 
4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/huUJRkzoVcfKCHX4oe3pSf/0).

Comment: Thanks @the-impaler !! That works perfectly. That query is much simpler to read and understand than what I was imagining I'd have to do.